# unit elements of a polynomial rings

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials

Simple question, How is the unit elements of a polynomial rings?

In particular, what is the unit element of the ring $\Bbb Z_4 [x]$?

Comment: For a (nonzero) commutative ring $A$,  a polynomial in $A[x]$ is a unit iff its constant term is a unit in $A$ and all of its higher-degree coefficients are *nilpotent* in $A$.  This can be proved fairly simply once you know the intersection of all the prime ideals of $A$ is the set of nilpotent elements of $A$.

Comment: Thanks KCd, thats is all I needed to know.